# Get custom action details in Apex

Tags: apex, custom-actions

I know that I could use the REST API to get info on which custom (or standard) actions are available and get the additional info on them (which is described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_action.meta/api_action/actions_obj_apex.htm)). But in order for me to get everything I need, I'll have to chain the multiple REST API requests (first get the list of available actions, then for each action get its details) so I wonder: is it possible to get the same info inside Apex code using some standard classes (something that could look like `for (Schema.Action action: Actions.Custom) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be resolved with the help of [QuickAction Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_quickaction.htm). It provides some describe calls to get available actions etc.

`QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Account')` - this method would return all actions (both platform and quick actions for Account, 
or

`QuickAction.DescribeAvailableQuickActions('Global')` - this method would return list of all actions (both platform and quick actions)